# 2D ArrayList initializing rows

Tags: java, for-loop, random, arraylist, initialization

I'm making a 2D Arraylist board for a Collapse game, but for now just doing a text representation. I create the board, but when I attempt to fill it up with randomChar(), all the rows are getting the same random characters.
What am I doing wrong?

```
public static void createBoard(int rSize, int cSize) {
    ArrayList<Character> row = new ArrayList<Character>();
    ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>> board = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Character>>();

    for (int c = 0; c < cSize; c++) {
        board.add(row);

    }
    for (int r = 0; r < rSize; r++) {
        board.get(r).add(randomChar());
        //row.add(randomChar());
        // board.get(r).set(r, randomChar());
        }

    //prints out board in table form
    for (ArrayList<Character> r : board) {
        printRow(r);
    }
    System.out.println(board);

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are adding the same row multiple times to the board. You must add unique rows :

```
for (int c = 0; c < cSize; c++) {
    board.add(new ArrayList<Character>());
}
```

Comment: Aaaaah, okay. I thought of that but didn't think that was happening. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because in following line you are storing reference of same object:

```
for (int c = 0; c < cSize; c++) {
    board.add(row);
}
```

And when you do `board.get(r).add(randomChar());` so you will get all same value.
You should use different array for different board object:

```
for (int c = 0; c < cSize; c++) {
    board.add(new ArrayList<Character>());
}
```